# html input type color display as text color code

Tags: vue.js, input

I am trying to use input with color selector in vue.

```
<input type="color" v-model="model.$.message_color">
```

First time I am using `type="color"`, but now when I use it, it automatically selects default value black and I want it to be null by default and also it displays like this:
[image]

I want it to be displayed as color code as text for example #ffffff

Answer (score 2):

here is an working example. Just created a reactive variable `color` in combination with `v-model`.

So after selecting a new color, the label text will be colored with `:style`-binding.

```js
Vue.createApp({
  data () {
    return {
      color: '#808000' // <-- will be changed after new input
    }
  } 
}).mount('#demo')
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>

<div id="demo" class="demo">
<div>
    <input type="color" id="head" name="head"
            v-model="color"><br>
    <label for="head" :style="{color: color}">I'm colored</label>
    {{ color }}
</div>
</div>
```